# Formal proofs using subproofs

Tags: logic, proof

I have been trying to solve this question for couple hours and I still don't get it. The problem I'm trying to solve is 6.14 in the link below.

[image]

This is what I attempted so far:

[image]

I'm sure this is wrong, but I don't know the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

**6.14** is **not** valid.

The *conclusion* can be **FALSE** and the third *premise* can still be **TRUE** : it is enough that **SameRow(d,f)** is **FALSE**.

---

**BUT** if **FrontOf(b,f)** allows you to derive **¬SameRow(b,f)**, in this case the argument is *valid*.

With it and the second premise you are forced to have **SameRow(d,f)** true and thus, assuming **Cube(f)** you have the desired contradiction, concluding with **¬Cube(f)**.

Comment: It's valid because you can't find a counterexample. So that's why the only way is to do subproofs but I'm not sure how to construct one with this. Do you know?

Comment: @ashey - why "no counterexample" ? If **Cube(f)** is T, then the purported conclusion **¬Cube(f)** is F. With **SameRow(c,f)** F, then **¬SameRow(c,f)** is T. With **SameRow(d,f)** F and **Cube(f)** T we have that **SameRow(d,f) ∧ Cube(f)** is F and thus **¬(SameRow(d,f) ∧ Cube(f)** is T. Finally, it is enough that **SameRow(b,f)** is T to satisfy the first premise.

Comment: Maybe **FrontOf(b,f)** has some relationship with the other premises ?

Comment: **IF** (big if) **FrontOf(b,f)** allows you to derive **¬SameRow(b,f)**, in this case it works : with the second premise, you are forced to have  **SameRow(d,f)** true and assuming **Cube(f)** you arrive at the desired contradiction, concluding with **¬Cube(f)**.